# deleting gh pages in terminal is not affecting on github

Tags: github, github-pages

I deleted the following files in my terminal but I can not see the changes on the github branch
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)

```
deleted:    adminindex.html
deleted:    createsession.html
deleted:    entryapp.html
deleted:    entrystyle.css
deleted:    indexsignin.html
deleted:    indexsignup.html
deleted:    indexspecificmentor.html
deleted:    mentordecisioncard.css
deleted:    mentordecisioncard.html
deleted:    mentordecisioncard.js
deleted:    mentordecline.html
deleted:    mentorlist.js
deleted:    mentorsdecision.html
deleted:    mentorslist.css
deleted:    mentorslist.html
deleted:    othercard.css
deleted:    othercard.html
deleted:    signinstyle.css
deleted:    signupstyle.css
deleted:    trialmentor.css
deleted:    trialmentor.html
deleted:    trialmentor.js
```

Comment: Have you actually committed and pushed this to GitHub? Because if not, this is all just on your local machine, nothing's been deleted on the GitHub servers.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting files, you should:

1. commit the change
2. push to github pages

Suppose you're in local gh-pages branch, the command may look like as follows:

```
git commit -am 'delete files'

git push origin gh-pages:gh-pages
```